# Dagesh at end of בראת

Tags: blessing, grammar-dikduk, spelling-variants

I noticed that in borei nefashot in the Artscroll Siddur and in the Koren Siddur the tav in word בראת has no dagesh. I was under the impression that the tav suffix for second person masculine past always had a dagesh so I was wondering why this might be.

Comment: It shows up in Tanakh too https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%9E%D7%97

Comment: Please consider accepting Joel's answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tav is one of the *beged kefet* letters, which always takes a *dagesh kal*, **when it starts a new syllable after a previously closed one** (i.e. the previous syllable ends with a consonant).

To quote from the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begadkefat):

> In Hebrew writing with niqqud, a dot in the center of one of these letters, called dagesh ( ּ ), marks the plosive articulation:
>
> - at the beginning of a word **or after a consonant** (in which cases it is termed "dagesh qal")
>
> (*emphasis mine*)

Generally, you are correct, in that for most verb types the tav suffix for second person masculine singular starts a new syllable after the previous syllable is closed by a consonant e.g. שמרת , לקחת.

However, for a ל"א verb such as ברא, the aleph in בראת does not close the syllable, and thus the tav takes no *dagesh*. For another example, see this week's *parsha* ([Shemot 33:17](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0233.htm)):

> כִּי-מָצָאתָ חֵן בְּעֵינַי

The tav at the end of מצאת has no *dagesh*, as the א does not close the previous syllable.

This also occurs with ל"ה verbs e.g. עשה. [See all the instances of ועשית at the beginning of last week's *parsha* for example.](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0228.htm)